# Why doesn't the pd.Series replicate the time column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to use the pd.Series to replicate a time column, but it gave me a completely different time, why is that and how can I specifically use the pd.Series function to replicate a time column in Pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel

# Get into data
data = pd.read_csv('someData.csv', header=0, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df = DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort(['time'], ascending=True)  # Sort by time

# Create a new df column using only df.time
df['time2'] = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(date) for date in df['time'])
df['time3'] = df['time']

print df.head()

                 time
567     1/1/2015 0:12   
566     1/1/2015 0:14   
565     1/1/2015 0:28   
564     1/1/2015 0:30   
563     1/1/2015 0:42 

              time2  
567         2015-01-12 21:43:00   
566         2015-01-12 21:43:00   
565         2015-01-12 21:43:00   
564         2015-01-12 21:43:00   
563         2015-01-12 21:43:00   

             time3  
567  1/1/2015 0:12  
566  1/1/2015 0:14  
565  1/1/2015 0:28  
564  1/1/2015 0:30  
563  1/1/2015 0:42
```

Comment: Did you try `data = pd.read_csv('someData.csv', header=0, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False, parse_dates=['time'])`?

Comment: Just did, time2 still different from time1 (== time3)

Comment: I can't replicate, it works fine for me with your 5 sample text values.  You should try to put sample data in problem, not read from a CSV only you have.  Maybe your date format is not consistent across all rows?

Comment: Actually starting from your df.head() sample I didn't encounter any issues. May you post a sample of your original someData.csv?

Comment: Your creation of the new`time2` column is overly complicated, just do:  `df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime( df['time'] )`  Or did you do it like that because some rows of `date` are not actually dates?  Again, it's easier to answer this sort of question if you provide a complete example data frame.  Otherwise folks end up guessing what your data looks like (or getting frustrated and not trying to answer at all!)